# VB.Net DataView Saved With Binding Navigator

Tags: vb.net, datagridview, bindingnavigator

Well, I've been working several weeks on my first real VB project. I have learned a lot, but I am stumped on this one.

A little background, the application saves downtime information from several machines and saves the details to a SQL database. I needed to pull that data back from the SQL table for the supervisors to update some missing information (downtime reason). I created a Datasource and dataset with a datagridview. I was able to save the updated downtime reason with the binding navigator.

Now I wanted to filter my data with checkboxes, (ie 1st shift, 2nd shift, etc). I took a step backwards and created a dataview, removed the binding source, and populated the datagridview with the dataview information. The filters are all working, but I can no longer save the information back to the database. I am wondering if I have something bound incorrectly, or if the code for the binding navigator is wrong.

I have included the code for the entire form. 
Please excuse my inexperience.
Thank you for any assistance you have!

```
Public Class DataEntry2


    Private Sub ProductionDownTimeTableBindingNavigatorSaveItem_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ProductionDownTimeTableBindingNavigatorSaveItem.Click
        Me.Validate()
        Me.ProductionDownTimeTableBindingSource.EndEdit()
        'Me.TableAdapterManager.UpdateAll(Me.ProductionDownTimeDataSet)
        Me.TableAdapterManager.UpdateAll(Me.ProductionDownTimeDataSet)
    End Sub

    Private Sub DataEntry2_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        'TODO: This line of code loads data into the 'ProductionDownTimeDataSet.ProductionDownTimeTable' table. You can move, or remove it, as needed.
        'Me.ProductionDownTimeTableTableAdapter.Fill(Me.ProductionDownTimeDataSet.ProductionDownTimeTable)
    End Sub

    Private Sub DataEntry2_Closing(sender As Object, e As CancelEventArgs) Handles Me.Closing
        Selection.Close()
        SelectDataByLineForm.Close()
    End Sub

    Private Sub xP2PopulateDataBtn_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles xP2PopulateDataBtn.Click
        'Create Connection and Dataview 
        Dim connetionString As String
        Dim connection As SqlConnection
        Dim command As SqlCommand
        Dim adapter As New SqlDataAdapter
        Dim ds As New DataSet
        Dim dv As DataView
        Dim sql As String
        connetionString = "Data Source=Controls-PC;Initial Catalog=ProductionDownTime;User ID=XX;Password=XXXX"
        sql = "Select  * from ProductionDownTimeTable"
        connection = New SqlConnection(connetionString)
        Try
            connection.Open()
            command = New SqlCommand(sql, connection)
            adapter.SelectCommand = command
            adapter.Fill(ds, "Create DataView")
            adapter.Dispose()
            command.Dispose()
            connection.Close()
            'dv = ds.Tables(0).DefaultView
            dv = ds.Tables(0).AsDataView
            'Filters for a specific string (word) in a specicfic column. 
            'dv.RowFilter = String.Format("DTEventReason Like '%{0}%'", "Engineering")
            'Filters for "Null" in a specicfic column. 
            'dv.RowFilter = "DTEventReason is Null"
            'Filters looks for any column that contains NULL
            'dv.RowFilter = ("DTReasonBadgeNo is Null Or DTEventReason Is Null Or DTReasonDateTime is Null")
            'Filters for a shift number 
            'dv.RowFilter = "Shift = 2"
            'Filters for LineID formatted as a string 
            'dv.RowFilter = String.Format("LineID Like '%{0}%'", "1N")
            'Filters for LineID formatted as a string numbers only  
            'dv.RowFilter = String.Format("[LineID]= '1'")
            'filters for multiple criteria 
            'dv.RowFilter = ("(DTReasonBadgeNo Is Null Or DTEventReason Is Null Or DTReasonDateTime Is Null)")
            'dv.RowFilter = dv.RowFilter & "and Shift = 1"
            'dv.RowFilter = dv.RowFilter & String.Format("and [LineID]= '2'")
            'CheckBox Filtering code=Search for Incomplete Cells Line 2 Only 
            If xP2IncompleteCellsChkBox.Checked = True And _
               xP2FirstShiftChkBox.Checked = False And _
               xP2SecondShiftChkBox.Checked = False Then
                dv.RowFilter = ("(DTReasonBadgeNo Is Null Or DTEventReason Is Null Or DTReasonDateTime Is Null)")
                dv.RowFilter = dv.RowFilter & String.Format("and [LineID]= '2'")
                dv.Sort = "ProductionUpDateTime"
            End If
            'CheckBox Filtering code=Search for Incomplete Cells on first and second shift only Line 2 Only 
            If xP2IncompleteCellsChkBox.Checked = True And _
               xP2FirstShiftChkBox.Checked = True And _
               xP2SecondShiftChkBox.Checked = True Then
                dv.RowFilter = ("(DTReasonBadgeNo Is Null Or DTEventReason Is Null Or DTReasonDateTime Is Null)")
                dv.RowFilter = dv.RowFilter & "and Shift=1 or Shift=2"
                dv.RowFilter = dv.RowFilter & String.Format("and [LineID]= '2'")
                dv.Sort = "ProductionUpDateTime"
            End If
            'CheckBox Filtering code=Search for Incomplete Cells on first shift only Line 2 Only 
            If xP2IncompleteCellsChkBox.Checked = True And _
               xP2FirstShiftChkBox.Checked = True And _
               xP2SecondShiftChkBox.Checked = False Then
                dv.RowFilter = ("(DTReasonBadgeNo Is Null Or DTEventReason Is Null Or DTReasonDateTime Is Null)")
                dv.RowFilter = dv.RowFilter & "and Shift = 1"
                dv.RowFilter = dv.RowFilter & String.Format("and [LineID]= '2'")
                dv.Sort = "ProductionUpDateTime"
            End If
            'CheckBox Filtering code=Search for Incomplete Cells on second shift only Line 2 Only 
            If xP2IncompleteCellsChkBox.Checked = True And _
               xP2FirstShiftChkBox.Checked = False And _
               xP2SecondShiftChkBox.Checked = True Then
                dv.RowFilter = ("(DTReasonBadgeNo Is Null Or DTEventReason Is Null Or DTReasonDateTime Is Null)")
                dv.RowFilter = dv.RowFilter & "and Shift = 2"
                dv.RowFilter = dv.RowFilter & String.Format("and [LineID]= '2'")
                dv.Sort = "ProductionUpDateTime"
            End If
            'CheckBox Filtering Code=Incomplete and Complete Cells on First Shift Only Line 2 Only 
            If xP2IncompleteCellsChkBox.Checked = False And _
               xP2FirstShiftChkBox.Checked = True And _
               xP2SecondShiftChkBox.Checked = False Then
                dv.RowFilter = "Shift = 1"
                dv.RowFilter = dv.RowFilter & String.Format("and [LineID]= '2'")
                dv.Sort = "ProductionUpDateTime"
            End If
            'CheckBox Filtering Code=Incomplete and Complete Cells on Second Shift Only Line 2 Only 
            If xP2IncompleteCellsChkBox.Checked = False And _
               xP2FirstShiftChkBox.Checked = False And _
               xP2SecondShiftChkBox.Checked = True Then
                dv.RowFilter = "Shift = 2"
                dv.RowFilter = dv.RowFilter & String.Format("and [LineID]= '2'")
                dv.Sort = "ProductionUpDateTime"
            End If
            'CheckBox Filtering Code=Show All Line 2 Only 
            If xP2IncompleteCellsChkBox.Checked = False And _
               xP2FirstShiftChkBox.Checked = False And _
               xP2SecondShiftChkBox.Checked = False Then
                dv.RowFilter = "1 = 1"
                dv.RowFilter = dv.RowFilter & String.Format("and [LineID]= '2'")
                dv.Sort = "ProductionUpDateTime"
            End If
            'CheckBox Filter Code Show all Data from First and Second Shift Line 2 Only 
            If xP2IncompleteCellsChkBox.Checked = False And _
               xP2FirstShiftChkBox.Checked = True And _
               xP2SecondShiftChkBox.Checked = True Then
                dv.RowFilter = "Shift=1 or Shift=2"
                dv.RowFilter = dv.RowFilter & String.Format("and [LineID]= '2'")
                dv.Sort = "ProductionUpDateTime"
            End If
            ProductionDownTimeTableDataGridView.DataSource = ProductionDownTimeTableBindingSource
            ProductionDownTimeTableBindingSource.DataSource = dv
        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox(ex.ToString)
        End Try
    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: The BindingNavigator can do its own filtering:  `myBNav.BindingSource.Filter = "..."`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's rarely a need to create a `DataView` explicitly unless you need multiple views of the same `DataTable`.  Every `DataTable` is already associated with a `DataView` via it's `DefaultView` property.  When you bind a `DataTable`, e.g. directly to a `DataGridView` or to a `BindingSource`, the data exposed actually comes from the `DefaultView`, which is why you're able to sort the data by clicking a column header in a grid.

If you have bound a `DataTable` to a `BindingSource` then, as @Plutonix suggests, you can sort and filter the data via that `BindingSource` using its `Sort` and `Filter` properties.  These have the same effect as the `Sort` and `RowFilter` properties of the underlying `DataView`, which is the `DefaultView` of the bound `DataTable`.

Comment: Thanks To Plutonix and JMCilhinney! I removed the dataview code, put everything back to populate from the dataset and used the binding source filters as you suggested. It is functioning. Now to clean things up and move on to the next step! Much appreciated!

Comment: @sds5150 If it all works well, please click the checkmark to move this off the UnAnswered list.  It also helps others find good answers when they Google.